# Global var editing from another script in Python

Tags: python, global

I'm trying to increment a python global var from another script, but it doesn't seem to be updating. Am I doing something wrong here?

I run `func()` multiple times during the script execution and it never seems to update `globVal`

script 1:

```
def func():
    from script2 import globVal
    global globVal
    print "glob val is " + str(globVal)
    globVal = globVal + 1
```

script 2 (different file):

```
global globVal
globVal = 1
```

Comment: Once you have found an answer which works for you, please click the tick next to that answer to accept it. This lets other people with your problem know which solution worked for you.

Comment: FYI, global variables are seldom used in practice.  You should encapsulate them when possible.  http://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/maintainability/using_the_global_statement.html and http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad

Comment: You should note that when you import `globVal` and declare it as global, it will take precedence over an existing `globVal`, if there is such variable. You may want to forgo the `func` function entirely, as well as the global declarations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you ***are*** doing something wrong (answering your first question)

You should move `from script2 import globVal` to the top of `script2` as that value is being imported each time as 1. After moving the `import` to the top, the `globVal` variable should update.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.